# Android new object class

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I'm trying to make a new "Time" class,

time.java

```
public class Time{ 
    public int hour,minute;
    public double second;

    public Time(){
        super();
    }
}
```

main_activity.java

```
Time newT = new Time();
newT.hour = 3;
```

but i get an error here:     newT.hour

error (in eclipse) "Syntax Error on token "hour", Variabledeclaratorid Expected after this token"

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: @Dan Did you accidentially import Time?

Comment: Added actual solution, dont put code in the main_activity class body, but put it in a method. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accessibiliy of hour is `private`, so you cannot access it from another class. Create setters and getters:

```
public class Time{ 
    private int hour,minute;
    private double second; 

    public Time(){
        super();
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) { 
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public int getHour() { 
        return hour;
    }
}
```

Now set it via `newT.setHour(3);`

Edit: I see you reworked the errors. The actual error is because you have put these lines

```
Time newT = new Time();
newT.hour = 3;
```

in the class body, I assume you have something like this:

```
public class Main {
    Time newT = new Time();
    newT.hour = 3;
}
```

But you cannot do such a thing, as you may only declare variables/methods/classes in your class body. Try this:

```
public class Main {
    public void myMethod {
        Time newT = new Time();
        newT.hour = 3;
    }        
}
```

Comment: you too added this line >>  private double String second; :-O

Comment: @Ankit Thanks. The private modifier was such an obvious mistake that I tend to ignore the rest.

Comment: Agree, even i was trying the same, but got this line and awaken by question asker problem how he made it compiled, pointing towards another issue but not this. :) :)

Comment: @ankit Well, isn't there some setting to compile anyway, no matter what compile errors the compiler encounters? Guess he has triple that setting.

Answer (score 1):

use setter and getter method approach.
make two public methods in your class to set the hour value and to get it.
that way you can use private variables.

otherwise you need to make them public.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like to know how you compiled this "`private double String second;`" line. (double String together  :-o ), ok now below is solution for you.

your Time class should be like this below

```
 public class Time{ 

        private int hour,minute;
        private double seconds;


        public int getHour() {
            return hour;
        }

        public void setHour(int hour) {
            this.hour = hour;
        }

        public int getMinute() {
            return minute;
        }

        public void setMinute(int minute) {
            this.minute = minute;
        }

        public double getSeconds() {
            return seconds;
        }

        public void setSeconds(double seconds) {
            this.seconds = seconds;
        }
    }
```

and do something like this to set and get hours/min/sec

```
 Time newT = new Time();
      newT.setHour(1);
```

Also import Time in new class you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

As the error that you didn't tell us about clearly states, you cannot access a `private` field from outside the class.